# How to start a CLI program and give input to it using a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a third-party CLI program I downloaded using Node's package manager. This program is started by typing the name of the program in a terminal. Once you start the program, the program expects the user to enter strings of characters in which the program will interpret at proper commands if the strings of characters are those it recognizes. I want to automate the process of reading lines from a file, and passing these lines are strings of characters into the program.

Right now when I look up for help on Google for how to automate a CLI program, all I get it how to write a bash script. This is not enough, as what I need is a bash script that opens up a program and then passes arguments to that program, NOT to the terminal itself. Basically I need my script (which will take the file to read lines from as the only argument) to do the following

```
run my_program
while there are more lines to read from the file:
    "Lookup"
    $line
close my_program
```

where "Lookup" is a string of characters recognized as a command by my_program, and $line is meant to convey that I want to pass the line currently being read from the file as an argument to the program.

EDIT: I wrote the following script, but it's interpretting "while read line" as an argument to pass to my_program. How do I make it so that it only interprets the commands inside the while loop as arguments to my_program?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        my_program
        "Lookup"
        "$line"
done < $1
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you need but you might find [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) interesting.

Comment: Can you show an example of actual interaction with `my_program`, showing prompts and responses?

Comment: have you tried `my_program < file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    my_program $line
done < $1
```

and run this script with input file as parameter

Comment: This only works for a single input, as in it only works for
"Lookup;
line;"

All the rest of the lines don't get executed

Comment: that I misunderstood question. I'll edit the answer.